# Unknown property 'StoreFrontController.productDisplay.Condition'

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom, custom-controller

here is the following custom controller and VF page code but i am getting error of Unknown property 'StoreFrontController.productDisplay.Condition'

```
<apex:page controller="StoreFrontController" >
<apex:pageBlock title="Our Products">
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!products}" var="pitem">
                <apex:column headerValue="Product">
                <apex:outputText value="{!pitem.Name}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Condition">
                <apex:outputText value="{!pitem.Condition}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Price">
                <apex:outputText value="{!pitem.Price}"/>
                </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

</apex:page>

Controller:

```
public class StoreFrontController {
    list<productDisplay> prd;
    public list<productDisplay> getProducts() {
        if (prd == null) {
            prd = new list<productDisplay>();
            for (product__C item : [SELECT Id, Name, quantity__c, condition__c, Price__c, stock__c FROM product__c]) {
                prd.add(new productDisplay(item));
            }
        }
        return prd;
    }
    public class productDisplay {
        public Product__c p;
        productDisplay(Product__c itemDisplay) {
            this.p = itemDisplay;
        }
        public String getname {
            get {
                return p.name;
            }
        }
        public Decimal getPrice {
            get {
                return p.price__c;
            }
        }
        public String getCondition {
            get {
                return p.condition__c;
            }
        }
        public Decimal getStock {
            get {
                return(p.Stock__c);
            }
        }
        public Decimal getQuantity {
            get {
                return(p.Quantity__c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like prop in .NET. In your VF page use `pitem.Condition__c` and `pitem.Price__c`. Also as per your code you may not need a wrapper class

Comment: @highfive
The error removed but now instead of having values i m getting like this 
{pitem.Name} {pitem.Condition} {pitem.Price}

Comment: Why you use a wrapper class instead of returning the `Product__c` list itself and bind them in the UI(VF page) ?

Comment: in this way it would follow MVC design pattern. isnt it ???